# OpenCV imshow window doesnt update itself

Tags: python, qt, opencv

I have the code as follows:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
source = 'test.mp4'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(source)

window = "Window"
cv2.startWindowThread()
cv2.namedWindow(window)
cv2.moveWindow(window, 10, 10)
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, img = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break
    # Convert the image to grayscale
    n_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

    # Apply Gaussian Blur to reduce noise
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(n_gray, (5, 5), 0)

    # Sobel Edge Detection
    # Sobel Edge Detection on the X axis
    sobel_x = cv2.Sobel(src=blur, ddepth=cv2.CV_64F, dx=1, dy=0, ksize=5)
    # Sobel Edge Detection on the Y axis
    sobel_y = cv2.Sobel(src=blur, ddepth=cv2.CV_64F, dx=0, dy=1, ksize=5)
    # Combined X and Y Sobel Edge Detection
    sobel_xy = cv2.Sobel(src=blur, ddepth=cv2.CV_64F, dx=1, dy=1, ksize=5)

    img = np.hstack((sobel_x, sobel_y, sobel_xy))
    img = cv2.resize(img, (1920, 1080))
    cv2.imshow('Window', img)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, I can see imshow window is opened but it does not update itself, so it stays blank. I got `Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket` message on the console. Could you help me if there is anything wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Are you on a LINUX machine?

Comment: @CocaColaCoder Yes, my scripts run on LINUX shell and I connect via nomachine

Comment: Try this: `sudo apt install libopencv-dev python3-opencv` and also try reinstalling opencv-python: `pip uninstall opencv-python` and `pip install opencv-python`

Comment: @CocaColaCoder Thanks for your suggestion. It didnt help unfortunately.

Comment: you've got a build of OpenCV that uses Qt. the official package `opencv-python` does not come with Qt support. you appear to be using a third party build. further, you appear to be having _localhost network_ issues. do you have any details to reveal about your system, like any virtual machine or container use? -- remove ALL packages of opencv. install exactly one, with pip. DO NOT (!) install opencv-python and opencv-python-contrib at the same time. do not install third-party packages (conda-forge, or whatever's served up by `apt`) unless you _need_ that.

Comment: why do you call `startWindowThread()`? that function is not documented, nobody should be using it, the only implementing backend (that I'm aware of) is GTK.

Comment: @justRandomLearner. It worked for me. I am using Linux. Nothing wrong with startWindowThread()

Comment: If you having black screen. Then use bigger file size. small file size doesn't work.

Comment: nothing wrong with startWindowThread? technically true. however, it's entirely useless with *no* backends except GTK actually implementing it: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/search?q=cvStartWindowThread -- "use bigger file size"? please explain how that makes sense.